# Credit Card (Authorize.net) VS Credit Card (saved)

Tags: magento-1.7

What is the difference between these two options. on back end they give different outputs and the Credit Card (Authorize.net) does not use 3 digits verification number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have a payment gateway(like authorize.net for example), but still want to accept Credit Cards for processing offline, you can capture the credit card information using the Saved Credit Card payment method.

When the customer selects this method from the payment method list, they will be required to enter the Name on Card, select the Credit Card Type, enter the Credit Card Number, and select the Expiration Date. If enabled, they will also be required to enter the Card Verification Number. You would than have to process these cards manually, like if you had a credit card processing machine on location.

“Saved Credit Card” Saves the credit card information but then you have to take it and manually run it through your credit card processor. Magento does nothing with it

The automated way is to use authorize.net (or other methods) which  sends the credit card info to authorize.net and does the approval process for you.