# Don't want to save credit card information in database

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I have used magento default payment method **CC Saved**. But, I dont want to save the credit card number in the database. How to override the core files in this case?

I tried with **sales_order_save_after** event. But not get the actual result as expected. If use this event, we can just update the card number as NULL. But, I don't want to save the credit card number in database.

I don't want to add 3rd party merchant. Because, I need to send the payment details to separate API. They will handle the payment process.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use a 3rd party merchant like Authorize.net or Paypal, you don't want to handle the PCI compliance, and data security of your customers payment data, etc.

With that said see other threads:

- [Credit Card (Authorize.net) VS Credit Card (saved)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10272/credit-card-authorize-net-vs-credit-card-saved)
- [Credit Card (saved) payment method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31943/credit-card-saved-payment-method)

Comment: @BOOMER You are right, But I want to send payment details to separate API. They handle the payment process. So, I don't want to add 3rd party merchant. Thanks

Comment: Its best to tokenize the transactions, so upon an order being placed, sensitive credit card data is transmitted over HTTPS (not stored on your server) So upon needing to capture or close an order the token is referred to and not sending new details.  I would consult with the payment API you are using for best practices.

Comment: I'm with B00MER on this one - at least with Authorize.net you have two options, neither of which require you to store CC details in your database.  Option 1 (default) when you submit transaction using their API you generate token that you store in the DB via response from their service.  That token can be used to lookup info from their system later manually or via their API. Option 2 - Add CIM (Customer Information Manager) pay extra fee / month but that token can now be used to submit additional transactions via their API without having to store CC info: Our fee $20, may be different for you.